# wrapping class method in try / except using decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I have a general purpose function that sends info about exceptions to an application log.
I use the `exception_handler` function from within methods in classes.  The app log handler that is passed into and called by the `exception_handler` creates a JSON string that is what actually gets sent to the logfile.  This all works fine.

```
def exception_handler(log, terminate=False):
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    filename, line_num, func_name, text = traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-1]
    log.error('{0} Thrown from module: {1} in {2} at line: {3} ({4})'.format(exc_value, filename, func_name, line_num, text))
    del (filename, line_num, func_name, text)
    if terminate:
        sys.exit()
```

I use it as follows: (a hyper-simplified example)

```
from utils import exception_handler

class Demo1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = {a class that implements the application log}

    def demo(self, name):
        try:
            print(name)
        except Exception:
            exception_handler(self.log, True)
```

I would like to alter `exception_handler` for use as a decorator for a large number of methods, i.e.:

```
@handle_exceptions
def func1(self, name)
    {some code that gets wrapped in a try / except by the decorator}
```

I've looked at a number of articles about decorators, but I haven't yet figured out how to implement what I want to do. I need to pass a reference to the active log object and also pass 0 or more arguments to the wrapped function. I'd be happy to convert `exception_handler` to a method in a class if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 16):

Such a decorator would simply be:

```
def handle_exceptions(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kw)
        except Exception:
            self = args[0]
            exception_handler(self.log, True)
    return wrapper
```

This decorator simply calls the wrapped function inside a `try` suite.

This can be applied to methods only, as it assumes the first argument is `self`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn.  That looks good except how do I make pass self.log into handle_exceptions?  There is no 'self' visible to it.

Comment: @RoyHB: Ah, I missed that you used `self.log` there, my apologies. Adjusted to use `args[0]`, but you can also make `wrapper()` take an explicit `self` argument with `def wrapper(self, *args, **kw)`, and use `return f(self, *args, **kw)`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `return wrapper` at the bottom of that?

Comment: @EthanBierlein: indeed there should be.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Martijn for pointing me in the right direction.
I couldn't get his suggested solution to work but after a little more searching based on his example the following works fine:

```
def handle_exceptions(fn):
    from functools import wraps
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        try:
            return fn(self, *args, **kw)
        except Exception:
            exception_handler(self.log)
    return wrapper
```