# how to decorator: 'undo' changes in try except statement by copying

Tags: python, exception, decorator

I wish to 'undo' changes in the try statement upon entering an exception, by settings on a copy first, and only if successful overwriting the original with that copy. I seem to have a solution, but don't know how to turn it into a decorator so my code stays DRY.

to illustrate:

```
a = 0
try: 
    a = 1
    1/0
except:
    pass

print(a)
```

output: 1 (and I want it to be 0)

a decorator for handling exceptions in methods I found here: [wrapping class method in try / except using decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218974/wrapping-class-method-in-try-except-using-decorator)

the decorator referenced above looks as follows:

```
def handle_exceptions(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kw)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e # or do w/e
    return wrapper
```

if I use this:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_something(item):
        try:
            self.items.append(item)
            1/0
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

then the item will have been added to the items list (e.g. a change of state has occurred before hitting the exception).

The 'add_something' method as I have it currently that prevents this, tries to set it on the copy first, and if successful, overwrites the original:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_something(item):
        a_copy = self.items.copy()
        try:
            a_copy.append(item)
            1/0 # fails here, state of self.items remains unchanged
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        else: # in case no exception is hit, overwrite
            self.items = a_copy
```

This works. But, I need to do this many times over, therefore I would prefer a decorator that handles this, such that the 'add_something' method can remain clean, ideally as follows (or whatever comes closest):

```
    @exception_handler
    def add_something(item):
        self.items.append(item)
        1/0
```

I want to have a decorator, the @exception_handler, that achieves the same behavior as in the code snippet above containing the try / except / else statements, to keep my class methods clean and crisp.

Comment: Why aren't you simply checking that the assignment will be valid *before* making the assignment? That should be much easier than trying to implement transactions from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think decorator is the right solution here.
1. Different methods will not have same undo requirements, so the decorator must take an undo function as the argument.
2. Even if you do that, the undo method might not have access to the variables that you modified in the try block.

I think a better approach would be write an abstract class (let's call it `Task`) which has `Run` and `Undo` methods but unimplemented. Then you can write a method which takes an object of this class as input, execute the `Run` method in try block and execute `Undo` in the except block. The benefit of doing this way is that the class can contain the shared variables so that both `Run` and `Undo` have access to it.

Comment: I agree - there's no good way to do this with a decorator (if you were exclusively dealing with data structures you could deepcopy and then do recursive copying back afterwards, but with classes that's infeasible).